# bashAccess different levels of a .config file by script

Tags: regex, bash, sed, configuration-files

I'm trying to read fields from a .config file using a script and be able to change its value. I am using the following code, with which I can read the value of the 'model' field, but I do not know how to access the following levels, for example, num_classes.

To modify the model value I use the following, which works:

```
VAL="new_value"
sed -i "s/^\(model\s*\s*\).*\$/\1$VAL/" $path
```

But to modify the value of the field num_clases, the following code does not work:

```
VAL="new_value"
sed -i "s/^\(num_classes\s*:\s*\).*\$/\1$VAL/" $path
```

The configuration file that I'm using has the following format:

```
model {
  ssd {
    num_classes: 12
    box_coder {
      faster_rcnn_box_coder {
        y_scale: 10.0
        x_scale: 10.0
        height_scale: 5.0
        width_scale: 5.0
      }
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Can you state your goal more clearly? Are you simply trying to change one of those fields, say, `num_classes` from 12 to another number? Is there a reason you're not using `sed`? Can you compile a [minimum, viable, complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that others can help you understand your issue on a smaller problem?

Comment: `'s/^\(num_classes...'`, The `^` anchors the search to the beginning of the line. Are you using `\s` as spaces? I don't think that works by default (if at all) in sed. Maybe with a `-p` (for perl) options. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter it worked! Thank you very much